# Identifying a Markov Process

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process, birth-death-process

Let $\{N_{1}(t)\}_{t\geq0}$ and $\{N_{2}(t)\}_{t\geq 0}$ be two independent birth processes with strictly positive birth rates $\lambda_{n}^{(1)}$ and $\lambda_{n}^{(2)},n\geq 0$ respectively.

Define $X(t)=N_{1}(t)+N_{2}(t)$ and $Y(t)=N_{1}(t)-N_{2}(t)$.

The exercise given for this situation asks me to identify which of 4 statements is true. The statement that apparently is true is

"The process $\{N_{1}(t),X(t)\}_{t\geq 0}$ is a Markov process."

Could someone help me in showing how this is a Markov process? I am confused on how to combine $N_{1}(t)$ and $X(t)$.

The false statements were:

- "The process $\{N_{2}(t),Y(t)\}_{t\geq 0}$ is not a Markov process."
- "The process $\{X(t)\}_{t\geq 0}$ is a birth process."
- "The process $\{Y(t)\}_{t\geq 0}$ may be a birth-death process."

Comment: Just curious, what were the other (false) statements?

Comment: @imranfat I added them in the question

Comment: Can you give the exact definition of birth process?

Comment: @Miguel I believe it is something like: A continuous-time Markov process where we only have one sort of state transition "birth", which increase the state variable by one.

Comment: What did you try? I think you can prove it using either the infinitesimal definition or the transition probability definition. Try to write the probabilities in terms of $N_1(t), N_2(t)$ and use that these are Markov processes.

Comment: I am not too sure how to start. I don't understand what the combination of $\{N_{1}(t),X(t)\}$ means.

Comment: It is a combination of two random variables. If you e.g. have processes $X(t)$ and $Y(t)$ you can define a joint process $\{X(t) Y(t)\}$ which takes values $(x,y)$ where $x$ belongs to the state space of $X(t)$ and $y$ to the state space of $Y(t)$.